# IBM JSR 352 joblogs empty

Tags: websphere-liberty, jsr352, java-batch

I run IBM JSR 352 java batch application on Websphere Liberty Profile server. The application used to write job logs, e.g.
C:\web servers\liberty_profile\wlp-javaee7-17.0.0.1\wlp\usr\servers\javnat-batch-server\logs\joblogs\Job1000\2018-05-24\instance.19401\execution.19401\part.1.log

part.1.log contains job execution information and exception stack trace.

However, currently, every time any batch job runs, the part.1.log is created but with the size 0. The file is just empty. I didn't change any configure. Could you guys shed some lights what the problem may be in this case? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please share your server config (server.xml)?

Comment: Can you explain what mechanism you are using to start the jobs ?  E.g.are you using one of the remote interfaces provided via the batchManagement-1.0 feature (like the batchManager CLI or REST interface) ?   Or are you using the JobOperator API?

Comment: Thanks Scott. It happens for every job.

Comment: I use REST API to kick off job, e.g.
URL: https://localhost:9444/ibm/api/batch/jobinstances/
JSON:
{
 "applicationName" : "Gradle___testing___javnat_batch_1_0_SNAPSHOT_war__exploded_",
 "moduleName" : "javnat-batch-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war",
 "jobXMLName" : "/Job1001",
 "jobParameters" :
 {
  "userId" : "Test_user"
 }
 
}

Comment: Does it happen for jobs that are executing successfully too (reaching COMPLETED state)?     If you can share your server.xml (with any sensitive data blanked out), that might give a clue too.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I tried to paste my server.xml here but it is too long. Can I attach file here?

Comment: And yes jobs were executing successfully to the COMPLETED state. Nothing went wrong except for job logs are empty

Comment: You could put the file on GitHub  as a gist..  or.. to start, what I"m looking for is a) the features you have enabled (the children of the `<featureManager>` element) b)   the `<logging>` element   c) `<batchJobLogging>` element    ...  some of these may be defaulted and not explicitly present .   d) Also, please share your *bootstrap.properties* file.

Comment: Hi Scott, here are they.

<featureManager>
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.1</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <feature>json-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    <feature>batch-1.0</feature>
    <feature>batchManagement-1.0</feature>
    <feature>cdi-1.2</feature>
    <feature>javaMail-1.5</feature>
 </featureManager>

<batchJobLogging enabled="true" maxRecords="100000" />
   <logging traceSpecification="JavNat.*=all />

Comment: Hmm... thanks, unfortunately I don't have any ideas.   Any chance you could try moving up to the latest Liberty fixpack (18.0.0.1) ?

Comment: I don't think I have a bootstrap.properties

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott. Yeah I may try the latest version of WLP